# How can I use header for C that has typedef enum, when converting code to c++?

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef

I need to use some C code in a C++ project but I'm getting build errors for one of the c original's .h files.

The error has to do with some typedef enum parts, which I undestand that c and c++ handles differently. (or c++ doesn't do)

Here is a minimal version of that c style .h:
(there's several more similar entries in the real file)

```
typedef enum {
   ILCLIENT_EMPTY_BUFFER_DONE  = 0x1   /**< Set when a buffer is
                                           returned from an input
                                           port */
} ILEVENT_MASK_T;
```

The error message I get is:

```
pihwdecode.cpp:35:99: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘ILCLIENT_CREATE_FLAGS_T’ [-fpermissive]
    if(ilclient_create_component(client, &video_decode, "video_decode", ILCLIENT_DISABLE_ALL_PORTS | ILCLIENT_ENABLE_INPUT_BUFFERS) != 0)
```

I can't start rewriting and rebuilding all the C libraries so how can I add this to the c++ project? I have tried to wrap the #include call in a extern "C" block but that doesn't help.

All suggestions welcome!
Cheers, Fred

Comment: This error is in your cpp file, not in the .h file -- you need to use C++ code in your cpp file.

Comment: C++ cannot be changed, that's how it works. There is no trick. C code must be updated to C++'s rules.

Comment: Yes that worked too!! Nice one Thank You!  Do you know which method is the more 'official' one between the one you linked and the one Chris Dodd suggested in his reply?

Comment: If you have working `c` code why not keep it as `c`? It is dead easy to mix `c++` code with libraries written and compiled as `c`. Just put `extern "c" { ...... }` where appropriate.

Comment: Oops, I just reread your question. As I now understand, you problem is *not* recompiling your c-code as c++, but using a library written and compiled in c, In that case, as others have said, you have to write valid c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick you can do is defining an overloaded `operator |` for enum types that are intended to be used as bitmasks like this:

```
ILCLIENT_CREATE_FLAGS_T operator|(ILCLIENT_CREATE_FLAGS_T a, ILCLIENT_CREATE_FLAGS_T b) {
    return static_cast<ILCLIENT_CREATE_FLAGS_T>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b)); }
```

This will then allow you to `|` together mulitple such flags without additional casts in your C++ code.

---

The reason this is useful for allowing more C-like code -- in C you can implicitly convert an enum to an int or an int to an enum.  In C++ you can do the first, but not the second.

Comment: Ok that actually compiles! And nothing crashing so far. Awesome! But could you please clarify for me, is it the '|' operation that is the cause of the break?  As then I could maybe just rewrite that part a bit.